# BLE scenario for transferring data

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-transfer, medical

I have a question regarding BLE.  It's my first time trying to use BLE and I am exploring some high level designs for a medical device.  The structure would be that the device connects to a stand alone controller-device (wifi disabled) via BLE.  The device would be collecting data such as heart rate throughout a 24 hour period.  At some point the stand alone controller would be disconnected from the device and connected to an app to transfer the data collected.  Can BLE handle the potential data size of this scenario? Is it fast enough to do it in a reasonable amount of time?

Thank you!

Comment: How often do you need to collect the heart rate using your controller device? Once a second? There is a standard GATT service for heart rate values, so the answer to your question is probably yes since other heart rate monitors use BLE as well

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Thank you so much for your response!  We haven't fully decided on the specs for how frequent but I would think at the most frequent once per second.  The heart rate and other health data isn't necessary to the primary function of the device it is a feature we're considering adding so medical providers can have more data to provide care and update treatment plans.  Good to know it's being used already for similar applications!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [specification list](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) provided by the Bluetooth SIG. Two documents describe the handling of heart rate measurements, the most interesting for you would be the Heart Rate Service specification (Download it here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/heart-rate-service-1-0/).

It contains a detailed description on how to transmit heart rate data via BLE. According to the specification you are supposed to use the 16-bit UUID `0x180D`for the Heart Rate Service. You can find the UUIDs for other services and characteristics in the [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/assigned-numbers/).